# Can I close a FILE without closing the fd?

Tags: c, linux

I've opened a `FILE *f` with `fdopen(fd, "w+")` and I would like to keep the `fd` open after closing with `fclose(f)`.

Is there an elegant way to do that?

Can I simply call `fflush(f); free(f);` or is that dangerous?

Or is there a way to change the internal `fd` to an invalid value `-1` so that `fd` cannot be closed by `fclose()`?

Comment: You could use `dup(fileno(f))`, i guess.

Comment: I prefer not using unnecessary system calls

Comment: I understand your position, but I don't think there is a portable way to do what you want. And doing a `free(f)` is a very bad idea. Also, a call to `dup()` is cheap, certainly not more costly than `fflush()`.

Comment: `fclose()` does `fflush()`. `fflush()` is called any way. My application does not have to be portable. Performance is more important. I hope someone comes up with another solution.

Comment: Please be more specific about "Performance is more important." I suggest to try `int fd2 = dup(fd); f = fdopen(fd2, "w+");` ... `fclose(f);` and *measure* the performace impact of the additional `dup`. Please add more information to your question: What is your use case? Why do you (think you) need to use `fdopen` and `fclose` and keep `fd` open? Maybe there is a different solution.

Comment: You'll get the best performance, and portability, by simply not calling `fclose()` at all.  Just `fflush(f)` and then operate on the fd however you like.

Comment: It's a server application, that should respond within 100us. So not calling `fclose()` is not an option, except there is a way to replace the `fd` within `FILE`

Comment: What is the reason for using a `FILE` object? `fscanf` and `fprintf`? Instead, use `sscanf`, `sprintf` and `read`, `write`. Too much work? Then you have to use `dup` (as already mentioned).

Comment: `FILE` objects store file descriptors internally. If you `fclose` the `FILE`, you `close` its internal fd

Comment: Are you using `FILE *` for network IO? Unless you are using 1 thread per connection a blocked IO will kill your performance. And `FILE *` doesn't support non-blocking IO.

Comment: @HAL9000, I'm using one thread per connection. But thanks for the hint, I've forgot about that.
Now I replaced `FILE` with a buffer from `libevent` anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the file descriptor and disassociate it from the the `FILE*`, there is one supported way:

1. Get the file descriptor with [`fileno()`](//man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html). (POSIX)
2. Duplicate it using [`dup()`](//man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html). (POSIX)
3. Close the `FILE` the normal way with [`fclose()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose). (c)

Now you only have a file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd really like to use a `FILE` object rather than a file descriptor, you needn't worry about `close()`ing the file descriptor: `fclose()` does this for you. Also, if performance is important, you should worry about all of the `fdopen()` and wrapped system calls defined in `f*()` standard I/O functions. Big thanks to all the comments!

Also see the [fclose man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose):

> The `fclose()` function flushes the stream pointed to by `fp` (writing any buffered output data using `fflush(3)`) and **closes the underlying file descriptor**.

Comment: Do note that any `write`, etc. system calls to the file descriptor used in `fdopen()` are invalidated by `fclose()`

Comment: I needed the `f*()` functions for buffering, which reduces syscalls. It's not just a wrapper.

Comment: @Cosinus I see... Did this answer help?